# Need to check the occurrence of file and add the few details of each file in data-table, if the file is absent need to mention

Tags: c#

i just got all the file details of the particular file and added in list.

```
string[] Switch_filePath = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.switch", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
List<DateTime> SwitchFileLMDate_List = new List<DateTime>();
List<string> Switch_FileName_List = new List<string>();
DateTime Switch_L_M_D;
string Switch_File_Name;

foreach (string CurrentPath in Switch_filePath)
{
    Switch_File_Name = Path.GetFileName(CurrentPath);
    Switch_FileName_List.Add(Switch_File_Name);
    Switch_L_M_D = Directory.GetLastWriteTime(CurrentPath);
    SwitchFileLMDate_List.Add(Switch_L_M_D);
}
```

**But how to check the below condition:**

**Please suggest any simplest-way any idea to do this:**

In a directory we have many sub-folders,need to check the file type .count,.data and .switch in each folder and store the file name  and the path in data table. If any one of the file type is absent in any folder need to mention the file is absent in data-table.

Captured result will be sent to mail, store the result according to that.

The result will be like this:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

Here i first captured the Sub-directories.Under each sub-directories if condition is checked. if file type is count add the count file details to the data table, if file type is switch......like that we can add values to the data table.

```
       // Getting the latest .Count file:
        string directory = "C:\\MainFolder";

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        DataRow row;
        DataColumn column;
        column = new DataColumn();


        dt.Columns.Add("Count_File_Date", typeof(String));
        dt.Columns.Add("Count_File_Name", typeof(String));
        dt.Columns.Add("Count_File_LMD", typeof(String));
        dt.Columns.Add("Switch_File_Name", typeof(String));
        dt.Columns.Add("Switch_File_Date", typeof(String));
        dt.Columns.Add("Data_File_Name", typeof(String));
        dt.Columns.Add("Data_File_LMD", typeof(String));
        row = dt.NewRow();
        dt.Rows.Add(row);

        var directories = Directory.GetDirectories(directory);

        foreach (string subdirectory in directories)
        {
            if (Directory.GetFiles(subdirectory, "*.count").Length == 0)
            {
                row["Count_File_Name"] = "Count File Not Found";

            }
            else
            {
                // Getting the values of count file
                DateTime Count_L_M_D;
                string Count_File_Name;
                string[] Count_filePath1 = Directory.GetFiles(subdirectory, "*.count");
                string Content = File.ReadAllText(@Count_filePath1[0]);
                string loadedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Content.Substring(9, 8), "yyyyMMdd",
                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
                DateTime Datevalue = DateTime.Parse(loadedDate);
                Count_File_Name = Path.GetFileName(Count_filePath1[0]);
                Count_L_M_D = Directory.GetLastWriteTime(Count_filePath1[0]);
                row["Count_File_Date"] = Datevalue;
                row["Count_File_Name"] = Count_File_Name;
                row["Count_File_LMD"] = Count_L_M_D;
            }

            if (Directory.GetFiles(subdirectory, "*.switch").Length == 0)
            {
                row["Switch_File_Name"] = "Switch File Not Found";

            }
            else
            {
                string[] Switch_filePath = Directory.GetFiles(subdirectory, "*.switch");
                DateTime Switch_L_M_D;
                string S_File_Name;

                S_File_Name = Path.GetFileName(Switch_filePath[0]);
                Switch_L_M_D = Directory.GetLastWriteTime(Switch_filePath[0]);

                    row["Switch_File_Name"] = S_File_Name;
                    row["Switch_File_Date"] = Switch_L_M_D;
                 }
            if (Directory.GetFiles(subdirectory, "*.data").Length == 0)
            {
                row["Data_File_Name"] = "Data File Not Found";

            }
            else
            {
                string[] Data_filePath = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.data", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                List<DateTime> DataFileLMDate_List = new List<DateTime>();
                List<string> Data_FileName_List = new List<string>();
                DateTime Data_L_M_D;
                string Data_File_Name;
                    Data_File_Name = Path.GetFileName(Data_filePath[0]);
                    Data_FileName_List.Add(Data_File_Name);
                    Data_L_M_D = Directory.GetLastWriteTime(Data_filePath[0]);
                    DataFileLMDate_List.Add(Data_L_M_D);


                    row["Data_File_Name"] = Data_File_Name;
                    row["Data_File_LMD"] = Data_L_M_D;

            }
        }
```

Result: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gyp7F.png)

Comment: captured all the values in a datatable. How to pass this resultset to the mail task in ssis package